# Is there a way to programmatically catch a notification sent from a webpage if opened in Android Webview?

Tags: android, webview

More and more websites are able to push notifications to desktop browsers (Chrome, safari etc...)

My question is that, say such a website is loaded inside an android webview, is there a way to programatically catch the notification content sent by the website?

Whether by an official support or by a JS hack.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As push notifications are using service workers: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications have you looked at `ServiceWorkerController` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ServiceWorkerController.html